# Need to update values in an array by comparing two arrays and hard coded data

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I need to compare two arrays and replace values if id is same and a particular field in first array is null or has some hard coded data(test). If this condition is not true, don't do anything and keep the original values.  Below are the two sample arrays:

```
array1 = [
      {
        "Id": "test1",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data",
        "newField": "test"
      },
      {
        "Id": "test2",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data2",
        "newField": null
      },
      {
        "Id": "test3",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data2",
        "newField": "dummy"
      }
    ]
array2 = = [
      {
        "Id": "test1",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "fname": "david",
        "lname": "john"

      },
      {
        "Id": "test4",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "fname": "Chris",
        "lname": "Smith"
      }
    ]
```

In these two arrays, if Id is same and newField from array1 is either null or has "test" then I need to replace "fname" and "lname" in array2 with hard coded "Matched"  And if these both conditions are not matched then the original values will be used

logic is similar like this:

if array1.id == array2.id and (arrar1.newField == Null or arrar1.newField == "test") then replace fname and lname with "Matched" else keep whatever is in there. In the above example since test1 is matched I should get below output:

```
[
          {
            "Id": "test1",
            "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
            "fname": "Matched",
            "lname": "Matched"

          },
          {
            "Id": "test4",
            "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
            "fname": "Chris",
            "lname": "Smith"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: I think you had asked the same (this time its two fields vs one at that time) question  a few days ago?

Comment: Yes @SalimKhan, I did ask a similar question and since the requirements were changed I was asked to post a new question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the changes in the old thread. Did you check that?

Comment: hi @sudhish_s, unfortunately that didn't work for me I am still trying to figure it out. Actually I need to check another condition in the place where we are checking if array1.id == array2.id. If this new field from array1 is Null or has some hard coded text "some data" then only  I need to do the update logic else keep it as is. I tried implementing this new logic in your code but couldn't figure it out as I am new with MuleSoft and dataweave. Would really appreciate your help in this matter. I am going to update this question and sample arrays for better understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this Script where we are iterating the second array and cheking if its ID field value matching with first array ID field Value  then updating the fname and lname

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
var array1 = [
      {
        "Id": "test1",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data"
      },
      {
        "Id": "test2",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data2"
      }
    ]
var array2 =  [
      {
        "Id": "test1",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "fname": "david",
        "lname": "john"

      },
      {
        "Id": "test3",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "fname": "Chris",
        "lname": "Smith"
      }
    ]
output application/json  
---
array2 map ((item,index) -> 
if(array1.Id contains item.Id)
((item update "fname" with "Matched") update "lname" with "Matched") else item)
```

[image]

Comment: @Zak01 is this you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Anurag Sharma, this is great. But I also have additional fields in array2 that I need to update with "Matched". How do I included additional fields in the same logic. I tried doing something like this but it didn't work:array2 map ((item,index) -> 
if(array1.Id contains item.Id)
(((item update "fname" with "Matched") update "lname" with "Matched")  update fieldname..3 with "Matched") else item)

Comment: @Zak01 you can do that like this array2 map ((item,index) -> 
if(array1.Id contains item.Id)
(item update "fname" with "Matched" update "lname" with "Matched" update Date with "hh") else item)

Comment: this is working for updating multiple updates. However, I need to add another condition where you are checking id is same in both arrays. They have added another field in array1. Now if the value of this new field is null or "hardcoded string" I need to do the same logic else keep as is.. The logic needs to be  if(array1.Id contains item.Id) and (array1.newfield == null or "hardcoded string" then do the same update logic else keep as is(item)

Comment: I've updated the question with this new requirements and sample arrays for better understanding the logic. Please see if you can help. I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creates a map for Array1 elements by Id to reduce the number of iterations through the Array1. I assumed that there can be multiple records with same `id` in Array1.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var array1 = [
      {
        "Id": "test1",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data",
        "newField": "test"
      },
      {
        "Id": "test2",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data2",
        "newField": null
      },
      {
        "Id": "test3",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "name": "data2",
        "newField": "dummy"
      }
    ]
var array2 = [
      {
        "Id": "test1",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "fname": "david",
        "lname": "john"

      },
      {
        "Id": "test4",
        "Date": "2021-11-05T12:53:00.000Z",
        "fname": "Chris",
        "lname": "Smith"
      }
    ]

var array1byId = array1 groupBy ((item) -> item.Id)

---
array2 map ((item) -> do {
    var array1Item = array1byId [item.Id] default []
    var newFields = array1Item filter ($.newField == null or $.newField == "test")
    ---
    if ( (not isEmpty (array1Item))
                and (sizeOf (newFields) > 0))                    
        item update {
            case ."fname" -> "Matched"
            case ."lname" -> "Matched"
        }
    else item
    
})
```